# How to count and group by month or years with month at zero

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to set up a small statistical module.
I am looking for an array containing for each month the number of events of my 'evenement' table.
With the query below I get the results but only if there is a result in the month. IF there is none, it does not appear.
My request:

```
$data = DB::table("evenements")
        ->select(DB::raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datedevenement) AS month, COUNT(id) as id'),
         DB::raw('ifnull(count(id),0) as id')
        )
         ->where('typeevenement_id', '1')
        ->whereYear('datedevenement', Carbon::now()->year)
        ->orderBy('datedevenement')

        ->groupBy(DB::raw('month'))
        ->get();



    return $data;
```

My evenement table :

```
id | datedevenement | typeevenement_id
```

I understand that my request can not invent months that do not exist. I wonder if carbon or laravel does not have something to list by month or year in a continuous way.

Result must be an array or collection with monthORyears->count(evenement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you.
With this 2 answers and a small serach i arrived to this solution (i have add somathing for order with current month for start point) :

```
$monthly_uploaded_product = Evenement::select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datedevenement) AS month')
    )
        ->where('typeevenement_id', '1')
        ->wheredate('datedevenement', '>=', Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth()->subyears(1))
       /// ->whereYear('datedevenement', Carbon::now()->year)
       ->groupBy(DB::raw('month'))

        ->get();

    $mois  = ["janvier", "fevrier", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "aout", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "decembre"];

    foreach ($mois as $mois99) {
        $arriveeparmoisrefuge[]= array(
            'mois' => $mois99,
            'total' => '0'
        );

    }
        foreach ($monthly_uploaded_product as $key) {
                $arriveeparmoisrefuge[$key->month - 1]['total'] = $key->total;//update each month with the total value
        }
    $sorted = collect($arriveeparmoisrefuge)->sortBy(function ($count, $month) {
        $currentMonth = (int) \Carbon\Carbon::now()->month;

        return ($month + (13 - $currentMonth - 1)) % 12;
    });

    return  $sorted;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing could be to do a foreach of months and conflict it with the collection, if not present add it.

For simplicity you can apply the method keyby() ([documentation](http://Https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-keyby))

`->keyBy('month')`

on your collection.

and then perform the foreach like this:

```
$months =["January", "February", ....]; 
foreach ($months as $month){
  if (!isset($data[$month])){
    $data[$month]['id'] = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked Claudio's answer, but I'd try another way.

First, I get a collection of my events:

```php
$temp = $model
             ->orderBy("date_field")
             ->get()
             ->groupBy(function($query) { 
                 return Carbon::parse($query->date_field)
                               ->format("m");
             })
```

Now, you have a collection grouped by month.

My second step was iterate with the collection `$temp` like that:

```php
$result = new array();
$temp->each(function($query) use (&$result) {
    $result["count"] = $query->count();
    $result["data"] = $query;
});
```

Now, you have an array with a collection to explore your data and a counter to know how much events will be realised per month. When you haven't event it's necessary to sanitizer with your frontend.

Hope that help you.

Reference:
https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-group-query-result-by-day-month-year/